# How to build a dynamic grid and only show three columns in a row (JSF 2.2 and BootsFaces)

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am trying to layout a page with Bootsfaces and JSF 2.2.  I like to show only three column in a row and then start new row but don't know, how to implement this.

```
<h:form>
    <b:container>
        <b:row>
        <ui:repeat value="#{ClientBean4.custs}" var="custs">
            <b:column col-md="4"><h:outputText id="output" value="#{ClientBean4.counter}" /> </b:column>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ClientBean4.counter == 0}">
                </b:row><b:row>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
        </b:row>
    </b:container>
</h:form>
```

after a long time, I wrote above code, but it's givng error like 'h:panelgroup' should be properly closed. It's giving meaning, that I started panelGroup and then closing a row, starting a new row, and then close panelGroup.

So, Is anyone have idea, how to implement a layout, where a row will have three columns (showing customer's object details per column), then close the row and start a new row. obvisouly, I dont know, how many objects will be in the list.

Comment: Please give us some more information. Do you mean a new row should be created when the user presses a button? If not, what should trigger this? Or do you want to replace a certain row with certain information with something else ? Depending on what you are after here, there are a number of ways to go about it.

Comment: Now I understand. Let me write up an answer...

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg: If you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and then especially the title part, you can use that info to edit the questions and get additional reputation for each accepted edit.

Comment: From a technical point of view, you don't have to put each row in a `<b:row>`. Bootstrap automatically "overflows" the columns into the next row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BootFaces offers a component that handles this. More specifically you can use `<b:panelGrid columns="3">` to achieve this. This will give you a dynamic grid system that will grow vertically as you populate it but retain the number of rows that you specify.

You can see the component in action here, https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/panelgrids.jsf

PrimeFaces also has a component for this, but I assume you want to use BootFaces as your original code uses it. If you prefer PrimeFaces, you can use the `<p:dataGrid>` component, which does something similar. This component even handles pagination.

Comment: It might be 'better' to use grid css with plain divs or whatever so you get responsiveness out of the box. Oh wait, I now see that BootsFaces has this built-in. I don't think PrimeFaces has

Comment: Yes, this component will produce a normal Bootstrap grid using divs. Consequiently, it even supports the usual style classes to control it's behavior on different resolutions.

Comment: My pleasure @Mr.Learner.

Comment: @Kukeltje, Most PrimeFaces components are actually fully responsive and support mobile - this is something the development team has been working on since a couple of releases back.

Comment: I know: https://forum.primefaces.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=4569, ;-) but not enough (no disqualification, just an observation). I unfortunately did not have the time to create patches. Might change in de not too distant future.